# Added a new field to user profile, how do I set a value for existing users?

Tags: entities, users

I have added a new field to the user profile on my site (i.e. in /admin/config/people/accounts/fields), a boolean value that can be either 0 or 1. Existing users have no value. How can I easily set a value for all existing users?

Comment: The duplicate only mentions nodes but the answer is exactly the same (just replace 'node' with 'user' if you use a code solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) Module to update field values

> This module augments Views by allowing bulk operations to be executed
>   on the displayed rows. It does so by showing a checkbox in front of
>   each node, and adding a select box containing operations that can be
>   applied.

- Create a view of type `users`
- Add `Bulk operations: User` field and choose `Modify entity values` checkbox to select your boolean field